# Angular Material Select default selected option

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular7

I'm struggling getting the default selected option working in my Angular 7 (Material) application.

This is the model:

```
export class Zone extends Resource {
  id: number;
  name: string;
  active: boolean;
  sensor: TemperatureSensor;
}

export class TemperatureSensor extends Resource {
  id: number;
  name: string;
  mqttTopic: string;
  zone: Zone;
}
```

The data it's retrieved from *SpringBoot REST*.
I use *angular4-hal* module to easily create Services to communicate with the server.

This is the code for the form field:

```
<mat-form-field>
<select matNativeControl placeholder="Temp. sensor" [(ngModel)]="zone.sensor" name="sensor" [formControl]="sensorControl">
    <option *ngFor="let temperatureSensor of temperatureSensors" [ngValue]="temperatureSensor">
        {{temperatureSensor.name}}
    </option>
</select>
</mat-form-field>
```

In the controller I've also tried to force the value:

```
sensorControl = new FormControl('');
ngOnInit() {
    this.getTemperatureSensors();
    this.getZone(this.route.params);
}

getZone(theParams: Observable<Params>) {
    theParams.subscribe(params => {
        const id = params.id;
        if (id) {
            this.zoneService.get(id).subscribe((zone: Zone) => {
                if (zone) {
                    this.zone = zone;
                    this.sensorControl.setValue(zone.sensor);
                } else {
                    console.log(`Zone with id '${id}' not found, returning to list`);
                    this.gotoList();
                }
            });
        }
    });
}
getTemperatureSensors() {
    this.temperatureSensorService.getAll().subscribe(temperatureSensors => {
        this.temperatureSensors = temperatureSensors;
    });
}
```

No way to get it work.

Someone know how to achieve that?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: where did you set the default value?

Comment: Stackblitz will help in this case!

Comment: this.sensorControl.setValue(zone.sensor);